# Десериализовать блок памяти в структуры без strict align

Tags: c++

Согласно правилам, приведение типа:

```
char* mem = (char*)malloc(sizeof(int));
int* numptr = (int*)mem;
```

Ведет к нарушению strict align, и это undefined behavior, ведущий к `Bus Error`.

Однако у меня есть блок памяти на, например, 500 мегабайт.
Целиком состоящий из скопированных в него через `memcpy` POD структур, где-то далеко в другой части галактики(процесса).

Мне известны все отступы. И простой, очевидный доступ до чтения/записи в очередную структуру выглядит так:

```
char* memory = (char*)malloc(real_big_size);
... //заполнение памяти
MyType* MTptr = (MyType*)&memory[offset_for_current_mytype];
```

Как описано выше, этот способ запрещен правилами языка. Вопрос: как именно мне считывать и работать с имеющейся памятью, при этом не копировать ее (она всё-таки 500Mb), и не отключая align оптмизацию.

Если запись&чтение в таком, казалось бы, простом и очевидном кейсе запрещены правилами языка, возможно есть способ получить подобного рода доступ только на чтение?

Comment: Вы для какой-то конкретной системы (железо/ос/компилятор) пишите или на все случаи, которые можно придумать? Если конкретно, то посмотрите на выравнивания и если все подходит (обычно malloc выделяет память с наиболее строгим выравниванием) то следуйте простому принципу -- "вам шашечки нужны или ехать?"

Comment: @avp есть сериализующий код, прекрасно со всеми оптимизациями работавший на `msvc-9.0` и `gcc-4.12` (таковы билд машины и это просто данность). Но при переносе на `Solaris CC - 5.12` он даёт `Bus Error`. Отключение align оптимизации может помочь, но понижает производительность 20-30%(вычисления длятся часами, и это существенно). Поэтому надо найти другой способ серилазиации/десериализации, вписывающийся в стандарт языка. Его и ищу.

Comment: @avp при этом, конечно, не хотелось бы делать десятки тысяч `memcpy(...)` на всевозможные разные структуры, когда простого приведения указателя было бы достаточно, для работы с блоком.

Comment: Надо смотреть конкретно на вашу структуру MyType. Видимо причина в выравнивании ее  полей. Как я понимаю, msvc и gcc работали в x86 (в ней независимо от оптимизации возможен доступ к невыровненным полям), а вот Solaris наверняка SPARC (там аппаратура таких вольностей не позволяет). В принципе, можете сразу посмотреть на атрибут [packed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) для структуры, но все же, тут нужно все тщательно потестировать

Comment: Структура, на которой происходит падение сейчас, состоит из `unsigned int` и 4 `size_t`. Не подскажете, где прочитать про ограничение доступа к структуре в SPARC, относящегося к моей проблеме?

Comment: Хм..., а о чем там читать? size_t должен выравниваться на 8, а int на 4. Распечатайте адреса элементов этой структуры при bus error (сделайте пока какой-нибудь указатель, доступный из обработчика сигнала и обновляемый в цикле где валится (не забудьте дать ему атрибут **volatile**))

Comment: Просто даже если после `int` будет какой-то padding на 4 байта, оно что при записи, что при чтении не должно давать проблемы же...

Comment: Если еще не решили проблему. Вот этот индекс -- `offset_for_current_mytype` -- он всегда кратен 8? И еще, с атрибутом *packed* работает? У меня просто сейчас нет sparc

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55079/discussion-between-arkady-and-avp).